# Allow inspection of source for Chrome Packaged Apps

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is there a way to allow a user to inspect the source code of a Chrome Packaged App? Or point the user to where the code is downloaded locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect it from chrome://extensions by clicking a "background page" link or opened windows' link. This will open a separate window of DevTools with HTML/Sources/etc in it.

> Or point the user to where the code is downloaded locally.
>   This is not what you're looking for, but [chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry) is the closest thing.